# Deleting the head node of a circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

Today I tackled this coding challenge:

> Given a circular linked list, implement a method to delete its head node. Return the list's new head node.

I would appreciate any feedback.

```
public ListNode deleteAtHead(ListNode head) {

    if(head == null){
        return head;
    }   
    ListNode temp = head;

    while(temp.next != head){
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp.next = head.next;
    head.next = null;
    head = temp.next;

   return head;
}
```

Comment: You don't handle a single element list where `head.next == head`.  You'll be stuck in an infinite loop if that happens.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dealing with a circularly linked list (meaning the tail's next points to head and the head's prev points to the tail) and assuming each node has a `prev` and `next`, you might consider this easier approach which does not require traversal of the entire list.

```
public ListNode deleteAtHead(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return head;
    }

    ListNode newHead = head.next;
    newHead.prev = head.prev;
    head.prev.next = newHead;

    head.next = null;
    head.prev = null;

    return newHead;
}
```

This should also work for a list with only 1 node (e.g. a head) assuming it is initialized with `prev` and `next` referencing itself.

Comment: Thank you for this approach but the problem did not have a prev and next pointers.

Comment: this doesn't actually correctly solve the given assignment. for `head.next == head` the correct return value is `null`, which doesn't happen with your code :/